# If I add an extension to AddControllersWithViews() will it also apply to AddRazorPages()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

If I use both `.AddControllersWithViews()` and `.AddRazorPages()` in an app, and I want to call an extension method on them, do I have to add it to both, and is it safe to add it to both?

In Asp Core 2.1, in Startup.cs we used to use the extension method `.AddMvc()`. 
In Asp Core 3+ this has been broken up into `.AddControllersWithViews()` and `.AddRazorPages()`. In an app which mixes both traditional MVC and newer razor views, the developer has the option of using both `.AddControllersWithViews()` and `.AddRazorPages()`, or just using the old `.AddMvc()`. This is mentioned in the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#mvc-service-registration) and can also be seen in the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/0303c9e90b5b48b309a78c2ec9911db1812e6bf3/src/Mvc/Mvc/src/MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L27).

In my app I have used both `.AddControllersWithViews()` and `.AddRazorPages()`, rather than just `.AddMvc()`.

```
var scwv = services.AddControllersWithViews();  
var srp = services.AddRazorPages();
```

If decide to add Netwonsoft Json support with `.AddNewtonsoftJson()`, would I need to add the `.AddNewtonsoftJson()` extension to both? Like

```
scwv.AddNewtonsoftJson()
srp.AddNewtonsoftJson()
```

Or can I use just one of the above statements?

Similarly, if I decide to add `.AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()` so that I don't have to stop and start the project every time I make a change in a .cshtml file, would I need to add the `.AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()` extension to both like this:

```
scwv.AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()
srp.AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()
```

Or can I use just one of the above statements?

[I realize the simpler option would be to change use .AddMvc(), and not think about any of this. But I am trying to understand how the middleware works, and whether adding an extension to one of them will do it for both, or whether adding the same extension to both of them is going to cause some problems or conflicts, since much of the underlying functionality is shared and all middlewares are being added together]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the `Add~` methods that you can run within the `ConfigureServices` method are usually built in a way that you can call them repeatedly without any additional side effect. For the most part, they just add or configure services for the depenndency injection container, and they do that in a way that does not add additional services on repeated calls or they replace previous registrations.

Service builders, like the MvcBuilder that gets returned from methods like `AddControllers()` or `AddRazorPages()`, are usually only a way to restrict additional `Add~` method for a certain scope. For example, `AddNewtonsoftJson` is only relevant as a “configuration” for MVC related setups. And there are many other extension methods that only apply to certain other setups. So to avoid having all these available on the service collection `services`, and heavily hindering discoverability, they are scoped using a builder pattern.

Behind the curtains, these builder will still add services directly to the service collection. As a result, it usually does not matter where you got the builder from, as long as you get it somehow.

> […] do I have to add it to both

So no, you do not have to add it to both `AddControllersWithViews()` and `AddRazorPages()`. Both calls will return an MVC builder that will add the services to the same service collection. So you can call `AddNewtonsoftJson()` on either builder.

> […] and is it safe to add it to both?

Yes, you could still call it on both.

---

That all being said, if you want to setup up MVC and Razor pages, i.e. call both `AddControllersWithViews()` and `AddRazorPages()`, then you can also just call `AddMvc()` since [that’s exactly what that method does](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/e276c8174b8bfdeb70efceafa81c75f8badbc8db/src/Mvc/Mvc/src/MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L27-L36). And then you no longer need to think about to which MVC builder you need to add the calls ;)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this really helps. As for AddMvc() - the reason I didn't just switch to it is I am concerned Microsoft has only kept it around for backward compatibility and might get rid of it in future (I may be wrong, this was just a suspicion).

Comment: Yeah, it might be possible that AddMvc will eventually be discontinued but I think it’s a safe bet that it will stick at least until ASP.NET Core 6 since there aren’t any plans currently to discontinue it. So you would be safe for quite a while to continue using it.